# ssms -- how to create table same as table on another server without data

Tags: ssms

I need to create a table similar to the one on another server.

How can I do this using ssms?

I am able to copy table from one server to another with data using Tasks | Export data but not sure how to create without data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the database you want the shell of in the SSMS gui.

Choose Tasks ---> Generate Scripts

There is a glossary of sorts on the left side of the panel

Under Introduction:  Choose Next

Under Choose Objects:  (1)Check **Select Specific Objects**.  (2) Expand the "**Tables**" section.  (3) Check the table(s) you want to generate.

Under Set Scripting Options:  (1)Choose Save to File.
(2) Set the Destination Drive and location.
(3) Click Advanced

There are lots of options under advanced start with these two, you may need to adjust others, but not likely.
(1)  Script for Server Version - Set to the server version you will be restoring the empty database, OR the same version as the source database.
(2)  Types of data to script - Choose **Schema Only**

Click OK

Click Next

Click Next

Should get all green icons on success.

Click finish.

Go to Destination database, open your file, execute the query.